# Как создать n-мерный (многомерный) массив на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

как в JavaScript заносить массив в многомерный массив, без обертывания в кавычки?

Т.е. есть массив - в него нужно засунуть еще 3 массива с 3мя елементами в каждом.

В конечном счете мне нужно получить многомерный массив такого вида:

```
var big_array= [[2, 5, 7], [3, 1, 4], [6, 8, 9]];
```

Я пытался добавлять массивы через **push** и якобы эмулировать массивы...

```
big_array.push("["+var1+","+var2+","+var3+"]");  //это пример добавления первого массива с данными (2,5,7)  

Но результат получается вот такой, с кавычками:

["[2,5,7]"]    //это big_array
```

Когда должен быть:

```
[[2,5,7]]
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `big_array.push(var1, var2, var3);`

Comment: @alexlz - вы добавляете 3 элемента, ТСу нужно добавить массив с тремя элементами

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
big_array.push("["+var1+","+var2+","+var3+"]"); // LOL

big_array.push([var1, var2 ,var3]);// не?..
```

Вы запихиваете строку и удивляетесь тому, что в массив добавляется именно строка? О_О

Comment: А почему я получаю немного не то, что хочется?


     > big_array
     [ [ [ 2, 5, 7 ],
         [ 3, 1, 4 ],
         [ 6, 8, 9 ] ] ]

Comment: а.. строка.. точно) спасибо )

Comment: Значит вы что-то делаете не так, тут без вариантов.

К тому-же я понятия не имею что именно вы хотите получить.

PS: рискну предположить что вы тупо вызываете push не для того массива

Если вы так и не разобрались - предоставьте код

Comment: Да нет, просто я var'ам присвоил одномерные массивы. Что и видно по результату.

Answer (score 2):

ПРИМЕР СОЗДАНИЯ МАССИВА С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ КОНСТРУКТОРА ОБЪЕКТА Array:

```
var arr = new Array(3);//Создание массива на 3 элемента
arr[0] = new Array(3); //вставл. в первый элемент массив на 3 элемента
arr[1] = new Array(3); //вставл. в второй элемент массив на 3 элемента
arr[2] = new Array(3); //вставл. в третий элемент массив на 3 элемента
//...
```

ПРИМЕР СОЗДАНИЯ МАССИВА С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ КВАДРАТНЫХ СКОБОК:

```
var arr = [];    //Создание пустого массива
arr[0]  = [];     //вставл. в первый элемент массив
arr[1]  = [];     //вставл. в второй элемент массив
arr[2]  = [];     //вставл. в третий элемент массив
//...
```

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ:
В JavaScript объекты Array являются динамическим, т.е. количество элементов может быть добавлено или сокращенно в любой момент времени выполнения программы. Исходя из этого вы можете добавить нужное количество элементов нужного типа в любой уровень многомерного массива, как в первом так и втором способе.

ПРИМЕР СОЗДАНИЯ МНОГОМЕРНОГО МАССИВА (10x10) С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ ЦИКЛА:

```
  var tаblе = new Array (10); // 10 строк таблицы

  for (var i=0; i < tаblе.length; i++) {
      tаblе[i] = new Array(10); // 10 столбцов
  }
```

Comment: очень своевременно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Пример создания любого n-мерного массива с любой длиной (параметрами), например 4-х мерного - 5x5x5x5, или, например 5 мерного - 5x4x3x2x2, - с соответствующими длинами (размером кластера). Внимание, индексация длины начинается с нуля.

```js
function createNDimArray(dimensions) {
    if (dimensions.length > 0) {
        var dim = dimensions[0];
        var rest = dimensions.slice(1);
        var newArray = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            newArray[i] = createNDimArray(rest);
        }
        return newArray;
     } else {
        return undefined;
     }
 }
//4-мерный массив 5x5x5x5 создается так:
var MyArray=createNDimArray([5, 5, 5, 5]);
MyArray[4][4][4][4]="MyArray 4d MyValue";
alert(MyArray[4][4][4][4]);


//5-мерный массив 5x4x3x2x2 создается так:
var MyArray_5d=createNDimArray([5, 4, 3, 2, 2]);
MyArray_5d[4][3][2][1][1]="MyArray 5d MyValue";
alert(MyArray_5d[4][3][2][1][1]);
```